query to importrange after 2 header rows in descending order in google sheets
modify a query for an import range so that it returns line 1+2 and then it returns line n to line 3
for example, if there is data as in Input A and Input B, you get Output A and Output B



Input A
InputB
Output A
Output B




Age Header A
Name Header A
Age Header A
Name Header A


Age Header B
Name Header B
Age Header B
Name Header B


3
Sam
10
Blue


4
Mark
9
Charlie


5
April
8
August


6
June
7
June


7
August
6
April


8
Charlie
5
Mark


9
Blue
4
Sam


10
Apple
3
Apple



The formula essentially should take inputs of HeaderArray, ValueArray
and apply a formula(HeaderArray, ValueArray) and import a limited range in order based on HeaderArray and a "descending" array of values that are not blank
   =QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheet", "spreadsheet!A1:Z2"); QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheet", "spreadsheetA3:Z"), "SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Col1 DESC")}, "SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")

Saw an approach to a similar issue here Fliped rows order from Importrange in google sheets but I feel it should be easier and achieved by modifying the query
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(SORT({
 IMPORTRANGE("1FbovD-T1ickPSat-RFsz_lk-HWZw6Ge-B87A4vhwLZc"; "Plan dnia!A2:M700")\ SEQUENCE(ROWS(
 IMPORTRANGE("1FbovD-T1ickPSat-RFsz_lk-HWZw6Ge-B87A4vhwLZc"; "Plan dnia!A2:M700")))\TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IMPORTRANGE("1FbovD-T1ickPSat-RFsz_lk-HWZw6Ge-B87A4vhwLZc"; "Plan dnia!A2:M700"));;9^9)))}; 14; 0); 
 "where Col15 is not null"; 0); 9^9; 13)


It would help if you could share sample sheet(s) with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

provided example

It's not clear if your second column is well sorted in your example, but according to what I understand, you can use SORT with a "helper column" created inside the formula with a sequence of the amount of rows of your range; that would sort it in reverse order because of the FALSE statement. And then you just have to query the empty values and VSTACK with the headers:
=LET(headers,A1:B2,values,A3:B,
VSTACK(headers,
QUERY(SORT(values,SEQUENCE(ROWS(values)),FALSE),"WHERE Col1 is not null",)))


Adapt the first line of the LET variables with your imported ranges

you understood correctly. and it works! Thanks
